# Anaconda MKL can't set number of threads

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda, intel-mkl

I was using `numpy` from anaconda to benchmark a big matrix multiplication ( `8192x8192` of type `float32`) like this: (in jupyter)

```
import numpy as np
a = np.empty((8192, 8192), 'f')
%timeit a @ a
```

The `numpy` is build against `MKL`. When doing the multiplication (continuously), I find the CPU usage of python is always 50%. I'm wondering why it isn't 100% (since matrix multiplication should be automatically palatalized). I therefore googled around and find two ways to set the number of threads `MKL` uses.

One way is directly using the DLL:

```
from ctypes import CDLL
mkl = CDLL('../conda/pkgs/mkl-2019.0-118/Library/bin/mkl_rt.dll')
print(mkl.MKL_Set_Num_Threads(4))
print(mkl.MKL_Get_Max_Threads())
```

which I believe gave me some unknown error code and failed to set:

```
-899695632
2
```

Another way is through `mkl-service` package:

```
import mkl
print(mkl.set_num_threads(4))
print(mkl.get_max_threads())
```

which also didn't success.

```
None
2
```

I'm wondering why is setting 4 threads in MKL keep failing and how to make it work. I'm under `Win7`, `64bit`. My CPU is `i5-2520M` which should have 4 core. My anaconda environment looks like: (abbreviated)

```
mkl                       2019.0                      118
mkl-service               1.1.2            py36hb217b18_5
mkl_fft                   1.0.6            py36hdbbee80_0
mkl_random                1.0.1            py36h77b88f5_1
numpy                     1.15.3           py36ha559c80_0
numpy-base                1.15.3           py36h8128ebf_0
zeromq                    4.2.5                he025d50_1
```

Comment: Are you sure hyperthreading is enabled? You can check by starting wmic (search for it in your start menu or run it from cmd) and running the command "CPU Get NumberOfCores,NumberOfLogicalProcessors /Format:List" without quotes.

Comment: It looks like MKL cares about number of physical cores and doesn't benefit from hyperthreading. Your machine has 2 physical cores and that will be the most number of threads MKL utilizes.

https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-math-kernel-library/topic/685075

Comment: @roro Do you know why would Task Manager say only 50% of the CPU is utilized? Is that wrong statistics?

Comment: Hyperthreading is a way for one physical core to mimic two cores under certain circumstance (useful for many general purpose programs, not useful for mathematical calculations). These mimic'd cores are called logical cores, and are what Windows sees. The threads are probably tied to a logical core, so Windows thinks only 2/4 are being used. Both of your physical cores are being fully utilized, but windows is thinking that it has two logical cores sitting there doing nothing. Since logical cores share most resources, this isn't really the case. I think your system is working as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Please consider this documentation:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-math-kernel-library-intel-mkl-intel-mkl-100-threading

The key variable is `MKL_NUM_THREADS`, which you can set as a global Windows variable.

I strongly disagree with @roro on this. The reason, why you are seeing the 50% is that you are not using your hyperthreading capabilities. Having said that, bear in mind, that there are 2 limiting factors to speed of calculation: CPU power and!! memory access bandwidth. Oftentimes the second will limit the speed to say 70% of your CPU power, cause RAM/cache cannot deliver data fast enough to the algorithm.

Getting parallelism right is among the more challenging parts of HPC.

Comment: The link you provided says this in the section on hyperthreading:

 "If the requested number of threads exceeds the number of physical cores (perhaps because of hyper-threading), and MKL_DYNAMIC is not changed from its default value of TRUE, Intel MKL will scale down the number of threads to the number of physical cores."

Hyperthreading doesn't generally benefit tasks rich in data parallelism, which is why MKL doesn't (by default) let your thread count exceed the number of physical cores.

Comment: That's, why i wrote my answer. It all depends on your algorithm, if you can profit from hyperthreading. I did reconstruction of MRI data in my PhD and found always ways to get to 75% of hyperthreaded cores. It did involve a lot of thinking though, in how to avoid cache misses as much as possible. Not easy. The work and also the code I used for teaching is all here: github.com/kvahed/codeare. Nearly every class has been tweaked to good extent for maximum performance.

Comment: I agree with that, maybe your objection was my loose statement on hyperthreading not being useful for mathematical calculations? I was thinking in terms of BLAS level 3 functions, like the matrix-matrix multiplies in the original question, where the bottle neck isn't on memory but on flops. They make up the foundation of high performance math libraries like LAPACK and other MKL implementations.